# Recorrer posiciones adyacentes de una matriz

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un juego que tiene como objetivo rellenar todos los cuadros del mismo color (en este caso los números serán los colores seleccionado por el usuario que esté jugando, y en una matriz con dimensiones de 9x9). El caso es que ya tengo realizado como generar dicha matriz aleatoria:

```
public static void generar (int tamano , int colores, int tablero [][]){
     for(int i=0; i<tamano; i++) {
         for(int j=0; j<tamano; j++) {          // recorro la matriz
              tablero[i][j]=(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*colores);
         }
     }

}
```

Una vez creada la matriz, se pide un color y por tanto si es el mismo que en el de esa casilla no hace nada, si es diferente cambiará el valor por el introducido y a la vez mira sus adyacencias para saber si tenían el mismo valor inicial para intercambiarlo por el color seleccionado. Por tanto si se ha cambiado el color en dicha adyacencia, comprobar también sus respetivas adyacencias. Tengo iniciado en la posición (x,y) = (1,1) que es en la que manda comenzar y por tanto el usuario no introduce la posición en la que jugar.

```
public static void jugada (int tablero[][], int color,int tamano ,int colores){ 
    int x= 1 ; int y = 1 ;      
        if (tablero [x][y] == color){
            tablero [x][y] = color ;

        }
        else{ 
            if (tablero [x][y] != color) {
            adyacentes (tablero, color, x , y);
            tablero [x][y] = color ;

        }
    }
}

public static void adyacentes (int tablero [][] , int color, int x , int y){

    if (tablero [x+1][y] == color){
        tablero [x+1][y] = color ;
    }
    else if (tablero [x+1][y] == tablero[x][y]){
        tablero [x+1][y] = color ;

    }
    if (tablero [x-1][y] == color){
        tablero [x-1][y] = color ;
    }
    else    if (tablero [x-1][y] == tablero[x][y]){
        tablero [x-1][y] = color ;

    }
    if (tablero [x][y+1] == color){
        tablero [x][y+1] = color ;
    }
    else    if (tablero [x][y+1] == tablero[x][y]){
        tablero [x][y+1] = color ;
    }

    if (tablero [x][y-1] == color){
        tablero [x][y-1] = color ;
    }
    else if (tablero [x][y-1] == tablero[x][y]){
        tablero [x][y-1] = color ;
}
```

Mi problema viene a la hora de recorrer las casillas adyacentes , por deducción lógica sé que debo recorrer la matriz con un bucle pero mis resultados no son los esperados. ¿Alguien me podría decir como sería dicho código para que mire a la hora de cambiar el valor en una adyacencia sus respectivas adyacencias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es un [rellenado por inundación](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) con adyacencia en 4 direcciones.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dadas unas coordenadas (en la ilustración es el centro) y un color (naranja en la ilustración) quieres rellenar de ese color todos los puntos del color original (blanco en la ilustración) que sean adyacentes.

Un algoritmo típico para hacer esto es en forma recursiva.
El método `jugada` solo comprueba si el punto dato tiene un color distinto al pasado como parámetro; si no es así no hace falta hacer nada. Si es así llama a `pintarRecursivo` que hace todo el trabajo.

```
  public static void jugada (int tablero[][], int color,int tamano ,int colores){ 
    int x= 1 ; int y = 1 ;      
    if (tablero [x][y] != color) {
      int colorARellenar = tablero[x][y];
      pintarRecursivo (tablero, color, colorARellenar, x , y);
    } 
  }
```

`pintarRecursivo` comprueba si está en un punto con color que coincide con el `colorARellenar`, si es así, le cambia el color y llama recursivamente para las 4 coordenadas adyacentes. Comprobando antes que no nos salimos del array.

```
  public static void pintarRecursivo (int tablero [][] , int color, int colorARellenar, int x , int y){
    if ( x<0 || y<0 || x>=tablero.length || y>=tablero[x].length )
      return;
    if ( tablero[x][y]!=colorARellenar )
      return;
    tablero[x][y] = color;
    pintarRecursivo( tablero, color, colorARellenar, x+1, y);
    pintarRecursivo( tablero, color, colorARellenar, x, y+1);
    pintarRecursivo( tablero, color, colorARellenar, x-1, y);
    pintarRecursivo( tablero, color, colorARellenar, x, y-1);
  }
```